# Updating MacPorts fails with Error: Requested variants "+python311" do not match those the build was started with: "+python37"

Tags: macports

I'm trying to update my MacPorts, and it fails with

```
Error: Requested variants "+python311" do not match those the build was started with: "+python37".
Error: Please use the same variants again, or run 'port clean xorg-xcb-proto' first to remove the existing partially completed build.
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_xorg-xcb-proto/xorg-xcb-proto/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.
```

I have installed python311 and python37, but that didn't help.

And I did try running "port clean xorg-xcb-proto" as recommended with no improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I needed to accept Xcode T&C

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

fixed it.  Everything is now working after a couple long builds to build newer gcc versions.

Comment: If it rebuilds gcc you have something else an issue as they should just be downloaded. Check you have run port selfupdate recently.

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that you had chosen to build xorg-xcb-proto with python37 in the past.

The fix I normally do here is

```
sudo port uninstall xorg-xcb-proto
```

The install xorg-xcb-proto with either default or with the exlicit python option you want.

I accept in your case if you have not got the Xcode command line tools then macports might have got confused.